Epic fhir appointment request
I try to get appointments from Epic Fhir. I use var baseUrl = "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4"
But I get status code forbidden.
Details of the Issue:
API Endpoint: https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4/Appointment
HTTP Method: GET
Authorization: Bearer token (OAuth 2.0)
Scopes Requested: patient/*.read, user/*.read, patient/Appointment.read, user/Appointment.read

It would help if you added more information about what you already tried. For example: Did you go through the steps to get your client registered, so it is allowed to get a token? You only mention a request, not the issued token. It is best to reach out to Epic for issues around that, or read the documentation at https://fhir.epic.com.

As already stated.. you have to "on-board" with epic .. even for their "developer sandbox".  Your error is basically saying "you tried to hit the RESOURCE server, but without the needed security-token to allow you in".      start at the top with the fhir.epic.com site (already stated by @Mir) .. but pay attention to "Oauth2" things like : https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2
